# web-to-lead form of suitecrm is not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created a web-to-lead form in SuiteCRM and copied the generated raw HTML to a page created in Wordpress admin as a single page post. However, the form is not working. In chrome JS console, I see an error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined in
>   sugar_grp1.js?v=L_gZ2lJDSmg-RmlYIZH3Lw:128 (anonymous function)"

The submit button is not working at all which I believe is due to this error. Any help is appreciated.

SuiteCRM: Version 7.2.1 Wordpress: V. 4.1.1 PHP: v. 5.4. Running on Openshift.com.

Original Question @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183332/web-to-lead-form-of-suitecem-not-working-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive there are issues with the javascript it pulls into the webtolead form, I would recommend stripping out the Javascript as it not required for the webtolead form to work, although it does add validation, I would put in html5 validation instead

Comment: Thank you @therealmjl the JS were just meant for validations indeed. Removed them and added HTML 5 validations as suggested by you and now its working